# ng-click doesnt work in input type submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I write a angular application that has a form with input type submit but ng-click doesnt work

```
<div ng-show="!addDate && tk.doTime != null && tk.test2" class="change-item-btn" ng-click="addDate = true"> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>{{tk.doTime}}</div>    
                        <form class="dateForm" ng-show="addDate" style="background-color:#dbf8f8;color: #152626; padding: 20px 20px 50px; margin-top:10px;" >   
                            <div  style="display:inline-block;width:50%;">  
                            delivery    
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <div class="input-append">
                                            <input name="date" class="input-small datepicker form-control" placeholder="date" type="text" style="color:black" />

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="display:inline-block;width:50%;">
                                delivery time
                               <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker">
                                    <input name="clock" style="color:black;direction:ltr;text-align:center" class=" input-small timepicker form-control" type="text">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <button ng-click="addDate = false" class="sbmtInput">cancel</button>
                            <input name="submit" type="submit" ng-click="deleting()" value="action" class="sbmtInput addDateTo" rel="{{tk.id}}-{{index}}-{{list.id}}" />
                        </form>
```

deleting function is

```
$scope.deleting= function(){

    $scope.addDate = false;
}
```

addDate value change to false but doesnt have any effect on html view
where i go wrong?

Comment: It should work.. Can you create plnkr for your question?

Answer (score 2):

This is because ng-click is in div with ng-show and in submit input as well. 
When you click the event is done twice and in divs ng-click addDate is set to true again.
In order to make this work, you should prevent propagation in input.
To do this, use stopPropagation method, available in your scope $event object. 
So the input code should be:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" ng-click="deleting(); $event.stopPropagation();" value="action" class="sbmtInput addDateTo" rel="{{tk.id}}-{{index}}-{{list.id}}" />
```